# Need to understand some regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression in a code(written by someone else), I am trying to understand what that expression means.

```
var decimal = /^\d[0,1]+(\.\d[1,4])?$/;
```

Can anyone explain to me what it does...

Comment: What about the explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/tY6mX7/1)?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - i was tagging 'regularexpression', 'nsregularexpression' may have been tagged by mistake.

Comment: My guess is they intended: `^\d{0,1}(\.\d{1,4})$` to get the most significant decimal numbers of some float less than 10 and positive.

Comment: I already tried that, but I couldn't understand what will it match

Comment: So `^\d{0,9}` would match 0,1, ... , 9 numbers up until a decimal point.  `(\.\d{1,6})` would match (AND CAPTURE) the decimal place and 1, 2, ..., or 6 numbers after the decimal point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order:

- `^` - Match the beginning of the input
- `\d` - A digit (0-9)
- `[0,1]+` - One or more occurrences of the characters `0`, `,`, or `1` —but see note below, this is probably not what the author meant to do
- `(` - The beginning of a capture group
- `\.` - A literal `.` (without the backslash, it would mean something special)
- `\d` - A digit
- `[1,4]` - Exactly one of the characters `1`, `,`, or `4` —but see note below, this is probably not what the author meant to do
- `)` - The end of the capture group
- `?` - Inidicates that the entire capture gruop is *optional* (zero or once)
- `$` - Match the end of the input

Re the `[0,1]+` and `[1,4]`, the expression was probably supposed to have `{0,1}` and `{1,4}` instead, which mean:

- `{0,1}` - match what came before either zero times or once (note that you have to remove the `+` that was after the `[0,1]`)
- `{1,4}` - match what came before 1, 2, 3, or 4 times

[Here's an explanation on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aE4gU1/1)

If we speculate that they probably meant [this](https://regex101.com/r/vT7sS3/1)

```
/^\d{0,1}(\.\d{1,4})?$/
```

...then in prose it means: Match any number that may or may not have one leading digit, and then may or may not have a decimal point followed by one to four digits. But it's still got issues, not least that the string `""` matches it, and (depending on what you're doing) you probably want to support values equal to or greater than `2`, which that expression doesn't.

Basically: If it's meant to validate a decimal, throw it away, and search for something that does a better job, such as [this](https://regex101.com/r/aT7dY2/1) if you really want at most four digits of precision and you want to capture the fractional portion (as your original does):

```
/^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d{1,4})?$/
```

If you want to allow any level of precision:

```
/^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$/
```

If you don't need the capture group:

```
/^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d{1,4})?$/     // Only allow 1-4 digits of precision
/^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?$/         // Allow any number of digits of precision
```

[That last](https://regex101.com/r/yG0iY4/1) is probably what I'd go with. Note that it **doesn't** allow leading zeros you wouldn't normally write (e.g., it disallows `02.345`). If you want to allow them, then just `/^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/`.

Comment: i think the author meant to validate only decimal values, that numbers, i.e. the number can be either a natural number or a decimal but a number. .
so is it working it that way..??

Comment: @kkk: No, not remotely; see above. If you just want to validate a number that can be `0`, `27`, `0.143`, `241.33432`, you want one of the last batch of regexes above (probably; they're a bit off-the-cuff, but...).

Answer (score 2):

The crucial parts:

`^`: Beginning of input

`\d`: A digit

`[0,1]+`: One or more occurences of `0` or `1` or `,`

`(\.\d[1,4])?`: An optional capture group, containing: a `.` literal, a digit, and a `1` or `4` or `,`

`$`: End of input

The full story can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/tY6mX7/1).

So some allowed input is:

- 80.94
- 41111111.44
- 4,,,1.44
- 30

Comment: if i am giving any value, which  doesn't have any decimal, it is returning null

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Ah thanks. Had to put up my spectacles, but I see it now.